# How to perform action on drop down select in message extension using adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have running message extension on Microsoft Teams using adaptive cards and my code base is NodeJS. This is how it looks like:

[image]

I am interested in how to perform an action based on Route Name selection from the dropdown.

The action involves changing/adding the fields (Title, Notes...).

For example, I have 2 routes in the drop-down  A and B.

For route **A**, I just want to show **Title** field and,

For route **B** I want to show both **Title** and **Notes**.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that dynamically.
However you can use Action Set with Action.ShowCard to show content based on your selection. I know that's ugly but it works.
I would suggest you to use task module for dynamic forms, cards functionality is quite limited.